# R Shiny: using if and else if statements in reactive()

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build up a shiny to:

1. manipulate the dataset with input choice;
2. calculate cumulative 'time' based on stage:
   i.e. 'time' for 'stage_1_plus' = time for stage=1 + stage=2 + stage=3 + stage=4;

'time' for 'stage_2_plus' = time for stage=2 + stage_3 + stage_4, etc.

3. create a summary table.

I'm also looking for a concise way to calculate the cumulative time.

The error message: object 'select.df' not found

Thank you!

Below are my codes:

```
data(larynx)

larynx.df = larynx %>%
  mutate(time = as.numeric(time)) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = "stage",
    names_prefix = "stage_",
    values_from = "time") %>% 
  replace(.=="NULL", "0")
  
ui = fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "stage",
                  label = "Select stage greater than:",
                  c("1" = "1", "2" = "2", "3" = "3", "4" = "4"))),
    
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput(outputId = "SummTable")
    ))
)


server = = function(input, output){
  
  contents = reactive({
    stage = input$stage
    
    if(stage == "1"){
      select.df = larynx.df %>%
        mutate(stage_1 = stage_1 + stage_2 + stage_3 + stage_4,
               stage_2 = stage_2 + stage_3 + stage_4,
               stage_3 = stage_3 + stage_4) %>%
        pivot_longer(
          cols = 4:7,
          names_to = "stage",
          names_prefix = "stage_",
          values_to = "duration")
    }
    
    if(stage == "2"){
      select.df = larynx.df %>%
        mutate(stage_2 = stage_2 + stage_3 + stage_4,
               stage_3 = stage_3 + stage_4) %>%
        select(-stage_1) %>%
        pivot_longer(
          cols = 4:6,
          names_to = "stage",
          names_prefix = "stage_",
          values_to = "duration")
    }
    

    if(stage == "3"){
      select.df = larynx.df %>%
        mutate(stage_3 = stage_3 + stage_4) %>%
        select(-c(stage_1, stage_2)) %>%
        pivot_longer(
          cols = 4:5,
          names_to = "stage",
          names_prefix = "stage_",
          values_to = "duration")
    }
    
    
    if(stage == "4"){
      select.df = larynx.df %>%
        select(age, diagyr, delta, stage_4)
    }
  })
    
  
    output$SummTable <- renderTable({
      select.df %>%                               
        group_by(delta) %>% 
        summarize(Median = median(duration),
                  Mean = round(mean(duration), 1),
                  Minimum = min(duration),
                  Maximum = max(duration)) %>%
        as.data.frame()
    })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Add `browser()` as the first line in your `reactive(.)` block, run your shiny app, then look step through the debugging browser line-by-line. You may find that `stage` is `NULL` or equally not useful (I have not tested, maybe or maybe not); it's not uncommon for some reactive blocks to fire before their dependent `input$` variables are instantiated, in which case `input$stage` might be empty. If this is the case (and in general should be done anyway), lead your `reactive` block with `req(input$date)`, it might just fix this.

Comment: Or ... something else: `if` blocks don't return anything, so your `contents` reactive block is never filled with data. After your last `if` block, add an explicit `select.df`. Now ... your other block needs to know to use *that* data, change to `output$SummTable <- renderTable({ contents() %>% group_by(delta) %>% ... ; })`. I suggest going through (again?) the shiny docs on [reactivity](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/#reactivity): it can be confusing, and you are not correctly setting up to be reactive to data changes.

Comment: Variables created in one block and not stored somewhere explicitly in a reactive context are not available to other blocks. Think of a block as a function, and once the code in one block is done, if its data is not explicitly returned (for a `reactive(.)`) then all of its variables are lost.

Comment: I think this error happened because `larynx.df` didn't produce, and you have to add `id_cols`  to your data as an indexing variable to input it in `pivot_wider()` function.